# Static dispatch on enum variant

Tags: rust

Given an enum `Token`:

```rust
enum Token {
  Identifier,
  Comment,
  // ...
}
```

I want to implement a method on a `Parser` struct that returns an `Option` whose value depends on whether a particular `Token` variant was found.

My naive approach is to implement a parser method for every possible variant:

```rust
struct Paser<'a> {
  current_token: Option<(Token, &'a str)>,
  // ...
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a> {
    fn match_identifier(&mut self) -> Option<()> {
        if let Some((Token::Identifier, _)) = self.current_token {
            self.next_token();
            Some(())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    fn match_comment(&mut self) -> Option<()> {
        if let Some((Token::Comment, _)) = self.current_token {
            self.next_token();
            Some(())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

However, this gets repetitive as each parser method has the same logic - and there are dozens of variants.

Alternatively, I could pass a `Token` as an argument to a unified `match_token` method, but this adds an extra value check:

```rust
    fn match_token(&mut self, token: Token) -> Option<()> {
        if let Some((t, _)) = self.current_token.take() {
            if t == token {
                self.next_token();
                Some(())
            } else {
                None
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
```

**In Rust, is there a way to do "static dispatch" on enum variants much like generics with types, whereby I specify a particular enum variant to tell the compiler which version of the method to use?**
What would be an idiomatic way of solving my problem, if any?

Comment: Have you tried `if self.current_token == Some(token)` ?

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks for your help! I wanted to keep the example somewhat simple but `self.current_token` is really of type `Option<(Token, &'a str)>`, which is why I can't directly perform the comparison (I think?) - I edited the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second function implementation looks pretty good to me. You can't do type dispatch on the value of an enum because the individual values of enums don't have types, at least not in Rust.

You can shorten it to one `if` statement in a couple of ways. As mentioned in the comments, if it truly is just a *value* and you want to compare for equality, you can do that with `Some` directly.

```
if self.current_token.take() == Some(token) {
  self.next_token();
  Some(())
} else {
  None
}
```

Otherwise, `Option` values are eligible for the `?` operator, similar to `Result`, so you can always bail out with a `?`

```
let current_token = self.current_token.take()?;
if current_token == Some(token) {
  self.next_token();
  Some(())
} else {
  None
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wanted to keep the example somewhat simple but `self.current_token` is really of type `Option<(Token, &'a str)>`, which is why I can't directly perform the comparison (I think?) - I edited the original post. Anyway, your approach seems like the most sensible way!